# What happens when mixing elemental mercury with sodium hypochlorite solution

Tags: reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution, liquids, mercury

Say you spilled elemental mercury from a thermometer and used household bleach on it, what would be the reaction if any?

Comment: More importantly, this is a very poor way to decontaminate anything where mercury has spilled.

Answer (score 2):

There are several redox reactions can be taken place when you add household beach on elemental mercury metal. However, this question is more like a homework question. Thus, I give you insight to the answer and you may read a bit and find out what's happening. This reaction is studies and results have been published (Reference 1), the abstract of which states that:

> The absorption of elemental $\ce{Hg}$ vapor into aqueous hypochlorite was measured in a stirred tank reactor at $25$ and $\pu{55 ^{\circ}C}$. $\ce{NaOCl}$ strongly absorbs $\ce{Hg}$ even at high pH. Low $\mathrm{pH}$, high $\ce{Cl-}$ and high-temperature favor mercury absorption.  Aqueous free $\ce{Cl2}$ was the active species that reacted with mercury. However, chlorine desorption was evident at high $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\mathrm{pH}<9$. Overall second-order reaction was observed between mercury and chlorine with an apparent second-order rate constant of $\pu{1.7\times 10^{15} M^{-1} s^{-1}}$ at $\pu{25 ^{\circ}C}$ and $\pu{1.4\times 10^{17} M^{-1} s^{-1}}$ at $\pu{55 ^{\circ}C}$. Gas-phase reaction was observed between $\ce{Hg}$  and $\ce{Cl2}$ on apparatus surfaces. Strong mercury absorption in water was also detected with $\ce{Cl2}$ present. Results indicate that the chlorine concentration, moisture, and surface area contribute positively to mercury removal.

I hope you will figured it out when you consider the standard reduction potentials of $\ce{Hg}$ and $\ce{OCl-}$ in any electrochemical series. For example, see Reference 2.

**References:**

1. L. L. Zhao, G. T. Rochelle, “Mercury absorption in aqueous hypochlorite,” *Chemical Engineering Science* **1999**, *54(5)*, 655-662 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0009-2509(98)00263-2).
2. S. G. Bratsch, “Standard Electrode Potentials and Temperature Coefficients in Water at $\pu{298.15 K}$,” *Journal of Physical and Chemical Reference Data* **1989**, *18(1)*, 1-21 (https://doi.org/10.1063/1.555839).

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Mathew, sodium hypochlorite can be used to remove elemental mercury. It is a redox reaction involving oxidation of mercury to $\ce{Hg^2+}$. There are various papers which discussed about the reaction of sodium hypochlorite and mercury and its role in removing of mercury. This paper[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11167-005-0337-5) discusses about the dissolution of mercury in aqueous solution of sodium hypochlorite at pH of 5.9–8.5 and the mechanism of oxidation of mercury to $\ce{Hg^2+}$. There is also another paper[2] which discuss about the role of sodium hypochlorite in the removal of mercury by wet-scrubbing method.

> The important step for increasing gaseous elemental mercury 
>   removal in wet scrubber systems is altering the chemical form of the
>   Hg to a water‐soluble oxidized species. This work focuses on the
>   removal of elemental mercury from simulated flue gas by aqueous sodium
>   chlorite in a bubble reactor. The effects of initial oxidizing
>   solution concentration, reaction temperature, pH and mercury
>   concentration in the inlet of the reactor on mercury oxidative
>   absorption in sodium chlorite were investigated. The results indicate
>   that higher concentrations of sodium chlorite favor Hg removal, with
>   a greater efficiency observed in acidic than in alkaline solution.
>   High temperature inhibits Hg absorption in aqueous sorbent when the
>   reaction temperature is lower than ca. 40 °C, and the removal
>   efficiency increases when the temperature is higher than that value.
>   In conclusion, the major influencing factors on the levels of Hg
>   removal are pH and chlorite concentration in solution.

**References**

1. I. P. SizenevaV. A. Val’tsiferV. N. Strel’nikov "A Study of Mercury Dissolution in Aqueous Solutions of Sodium Hypochlorite" *Russian Journal of Applied Chemistry* **April 2005**, Volume 78, Issue 4, pp 546–548 ([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11167-005-0337-5))
2. Y. Zhao  S.T. Liu  C.M. Chen  X.Y. Ma "Removal of Elemental Mercury by Sodium Chlorite Solution" **28 February 2008** (https://doi.org/10.1002/ceat.200700381)
3. https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/98JD02304